# Loading bar over status bar?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've seen several apps do this, and i've been wondering how it's done. If you look at the Wunderkit app, when it loads something, there's a blue animated bar that slides down to cover the status bar until it finishes loading. How is this done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can subclass UIWindow.
And set it windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;

code:

```
@interface CHLoadingWindow : UIWindow

@implementation CHLoadingWindow
- (id)init
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    self.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;
    // then draw your UI
  }
  return self;
} 
@end
```

use it:

```
CHLoadingWindow *loading = [[CHLoadingWindow alloc] init];
[loading makeKeyAndVisible];
```

discover it:

```
[loading release];
loading = nil;

[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0] makeKeyWindow];
```

Comment: Can you provide more of an explanation for this? I'm unable to get this code to work.